# Why my query return repeating records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables.

```
Complaints, Categories, SubCategories
```

Primary keys of Categories is foreign in Complaints table i.e. Cat_ID

Primary key of Categories table is foreign in SubCategories i.e. Category_ID

When I join Complaints with Categories then it works fine i.e. unique rows but when I join with SubCategories then it repeats each record. I have tried LEFT, RIGHT, INNER but nothing works.

```
Select *
        From dbo.Complaints Comp
        inner Join Categories Cat
        ON cat.CategoryID= Comp.Cat_ID
        inner join SubCategories scat
        ON scat.Category_ID= cat.CategoryID
```

SubCategories:

[image]

Categories:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Complaints table:

[image]

Comment: Guessing here but are you sure the joined columns in the last join are correct? I\`m thinking something like this might work `ON scat.Category_ID= cat.SubcategoryID`

Comment: No, bcz Primary key of Categories is foreign in sub categories not the opposite

Comment: If there are multiple complaints and subcategories then it will show multiple, can you add data and expected result.

Comment: update your question and show  the result you obtain  please

Comment: Is there not a column in `Complaints` that identifies the sub-category that it's related to? If not, how are we meant to constrain the join in any meaningful way and not pull back all subcategories that related to the category that *is* linked to the complaint?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there is, check the question now

Comment: what exactly you need. for a categories there are lot of subcategories so you will get multiple rows.. what is your requirement

Comment: what do you want in output add that also, like all sub_categories separated by comma or any one from matching or any particular one?

Comment: What exaclty you are trying to get from subcategories. If that is clear you can write query very easily. Please be specific

Comment: Complaints are not related to subcategories. But you join them still. If a category has 2 subcategories and 3 complaints you get 2 x 3 = 6 result rows. If you don't want this, what else do you want? It would be best you showed a minimal example like this: 2 subcategories, 3 complaints, few columns from the tables, the six rows you get, and the rows you want to get instead.

Comment: @Covert  .. i have posted an answer  hope is useful and clear

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to check if the rows are really unique? I've worked once with tables with several rows and I've got something similar to your issue because the rows were not unique. It was a column that was different

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a left join to subcategory and to *use* the subcategory information contained in the complaints table:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Complaints Comp
INNER JOIN Categories Cat
    ON cat.CategoryID = Comp.Cat_ID
LEFT JOIN SubCategories scat
    ON scat.Category_ID = cat.CategoryID
        AND scat.SubCategoryID = Comp.SubCat_ID
```

(I'd also recommend using `null`s rather than `0`s to represent `no subcategory`, which is what I assume the `0`s stand for)

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert SubCategoryId in Complaints table then it will work as your desire out put. And base on this you need to change your query

```
Select *
        From dbo.Complaints Comp
        inner join SubCategories scat
        ON scat.SubCategoryId= Comp.SubCategoryId
        inner Join Categories Cat
        ON cat.CategoryID= scat.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have subcategory ID in the Complaints table then there is no any way to identify which subcategory should be used. So you get all subcategories for each category. And it is the source of duplicates.

Add SubCat_Id to the Complaints table and join it with Subcategories on this field.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have 8 subcategories related  to category = 1  so when you join the category obtained  by  Complaints  (value = 1) to subcategories  you join all the 8  possible values

in this case  if you don't any columns form subcategories in select  the simplest solution is the use of distinct clause   eg:

```
Select DISTINCT Comp.*, Cat.*
    From dbo.Complaints Comp
    inner Join Categories Cat
    ON cat.CategoryID= Comp.Cat_ID
    inner join SubCategories scat
    ON scat.Category_ID= cat.CategoryID
```

Otherwsie you use also column for subcategories  as with select *  .. the row are not exactly repated  because you have (at least) the different subcategory related  to join with category 1

try using explicit column name (and not *)

```
Select DISTINCT Comp.complainID
   , Comp.Mode_ID
   , Comp.Cat_Id
   , ...
   , Cat.CategoryID
   , Cat.Name
    From dbo.Complaints Comp
    inner Join Categories Cat
    ON cat.CategoryID= Comp.Cat_ID
    inner join SubCategories scat
    ON scat.Category_ID= cat.CategoryID
```

Comment: sorry but still repeats